# how to solve a simple mixing operation in gekko?

Tags: gekko

I am trying to solve a simple mixing operation in gekko. The mixer `mx` takes two inlet streams `Feed1` and `Feed2`. The expected result is that mass flow of outlet stream `mx.outlet` should be the summation of mass flows of the inlet streams. 
Here is what I have tried.

```
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
m = GEKKO(remote=False)    

f = chemical.Flowsheet(m)
P = chemical.Properties(m)

c1 = P.compound('Butane')
c2 = P.compound('Propane')

feed1 = f.stream()
m_feed1 = f.massflows(sn= feed1.name)
m_feed1.mdot = 200
m_feed1.mdoti = [50,150]

feed2= f.stream()
m_feed2 = f.massflows(sn= feed2.name)
m_feed2.mdot = 200
m_feed2.mdoti = [50,150]      

mx = f.mixer(ni=2)
mx.inlet = [feed1.name,feed2.name]
m.options.SOLVER = 1

mf = f.massflows(sn = mx.outlet)
m.solve()
```

The code runs successfully. However, on  `mf.mdot` seems to output incorrect value [-1.8220132454e-06]. The expected value is 400. Any help , what is wrong with my code?

Comment: The issue is that your mass flow ```mdot``` and component mass flow ```mdoti``` variables are calculated when they need to be fixed. Also your molar flow variables on the inlet streams are calculated. It is a matter of flipping the specs (fixed/calculated) on the variables. I need to make those easier to use so I'm adding some new functions to Gekko that will be available in the next version. I'll delay my response to this question until after an easier fix is ready. The Chemical module is new and needs more development to be user friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is source code that works for this mixing application:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
import json

m = GEKKO(remote=False)    

f = chemical.Flowsheet(m)
P = chemical.Properties(m)

# define compounds
c1 = P.compound('Butane')
c2 = P.compound('Propane')

# create feed streams
feed1 = f.stream(fixed=False)
feed2 = f.stream(fixed=False)

# create massflows objects
m_feed1 = f.massflows(sn=feed1.name)
m_feed2 = f.massflows(sn=feed2.name)

# create mixer
mx = f.mixer(ni=2)

# connect feed streams to massflows objects
f.connect(feed1,mx.inlet[0])
f.connect(feed2,mx.inlet[1])
m.options.SOLVER = 1

mf = f.massflows(sn = mx.outlet)

# specify mass inlet flows
mi = [50,150]
for i in range(2):
    m.fix(m_feed1.mdoti[i],val=mi[i])
    m.fix(m_feed2.mdoti[i],val=mi[i])
# fix pressure and temperature
m.fix(feed1.P,val=101325)
m.fix(feed2.P,val=101325)
m.fix(feed1.T,val=300)
m.fix(feed2.T,val=305)

m.solve(disp=True)

# print results
print(f'The total massflow out is {mf.mdot.value}')

print('')

# get additional solution information
with open(m.path+'//results.json') as f:
    r = json.load(f)
for name, val in r.items():
    print(f'{name}={val[0]}')
```

Below is the solver output. This will only work with APM 0.9.1 and Gekko v0.2.3 (release coming Aug 2019). The thermo and flowsheet object libraries were released with v0.2.2 and there are several features that are still under development. The next release should resolve many of them.

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 0.9.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------


 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  6
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  19
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  44
   Equations    :  2
   Residuals    :  2

 Number of state variables:    14
 Number of total equations: -  14
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    0

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------

 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  3.86642E-16  1.99000E+02
    1  4.39087E-18  1.11937E+01
    2  8.33448E-19  6.05819E-01
    3  1.84640E-19  1.62783E-01
    4  2.91981E-20  7.21250E-02
    5  1.55439E-21  2.28110E-02
    6  5.51232E-24  1.21437E-03
    7  7.03139E-29  4.30650E-06
    8  7.03139E-29  4.30650E-06
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.0469 sec
 Objective      :  0.
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------


v1 not found in results file
The total massflow out is [400.0]

time=0.0
feed1.h=44154989.486
feed1.x[2]=0.79815448476
feed1.vdot=104.9180373
feed1.dens=0.040621756423
feed1.c[1]=0.0081993193551
feed1.c[2]=0.032422437068
feed1.mdot=200.0
feed1.y[1]=0.25
feed1.y[2]=0.75
feed1.sfrc=0.0
feed1.lfrc=0.0
feed1.vfrc=1.0
feed2.h=44552246.421
feed2.x[2]=0.79815448476
feed2.vdot=106.66667125
feed2.dens=0.03995582599
feed2.c[1]=0.0080649042837
feed2.c[2]=0.031890921707
feed2.mdot=200.0
feed2.y[1]=0.25
feed2.y[2]=0.75
feed2.sfrc=0.0
feed2.lfrc=0.0
feed2.vfrc=1.0
mixer5.outlet.t=381.10062836
mixer5.outlet.h=44353617.96
mixer5.outlet.ndot=8.5239099109
mixer5.outlet.x[1]=0.20184551524
mixer5.outlet.x[2]=0.79815448476
mixer5.outlet.vdot=1.5797241143
mixer5.outlet.dens=5.5635215396
mixer5.outlet.c[1]=1.0891224437
mixer5.outlet.c[2]=4.3066994177
mixer5.outlet.mdot=400.0
mixer5.outlet.y[1]=0.25
mixer5.outlet.y[2]=0.75
mixer5.outlet.sfrc=0.0
mixer5.outlet.lfrc=1.0
mixer5.outlet.vfrc=0.0
v2=300.0
v3=4.2619549555
v4=0.20184551524
v5=0.79815448476
v6=101325.0
v7=305.0
v8=4.2619549555
v9=0.20184551524
v10=0.79815448476
v11=200.0
v12=50.0
v13=150.0
v14=200.0
v15=50.0
v16=150.0
v17=400.0
v18=100.0
v19=300.0
```

Comment: Thanks @John , I will wait for the next release.  From the above code, it seems , the user has to fix the pressure and temperature manually. Or  is there any way that `mixer` object can solve for temperature as well based on heat balance?

Comment: Yes, the temperature is solved based on the heat balance. I fixed the inlet temperatures but the outlet temperature is calculated. You can display the outlet temperature with: ```print(f"The outlet temperature is {r[mx.name+'.outlet.t']}")```. Before the solution, you can also connect a variable to the outlet temperature. That opens you up to fix the outlet while calculating an inlet temperature to match the fixed outlet. One thing to watch is that I had both inlet streams as vapor and the outlet is liquid so the temperature is elevated. You would need to do the VLE calcs or specify phases.

Comment: I'll switch the default to liquid for all models in release 0.2.3. Otherwise, you can specify the phase with ```f.set_phase(y,phase='vapor'):``` as shown in the documentation: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chemical.html

Comment: great! these are really exciting new features towards the way of making gekko a full fledged process simulation ,  control and optimization tool.