# How do I get GEKKO chemical flowsheet mixer object to solve

Tags: python, gekko

I am exploring the Gekko chemical library and flowsheet implementation.  I defined compounds Propylene, Propane, Butane and Pentane and two stream with differing fractions of the compounds and  molar flow rates for streams.  I want to blend these streams and calculate the total molar flow rate and molar fractions of the combined stream.

The result I get is:
`Mole fraction in blended stream is: [[0.25], [0.25], [0.25], [0.25]]`. It appears to be the initialised values for the outlet stream.

I have perused this StackOverflow link [here] [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57219636/how-to-solve-a-simple-mixing-operation-in-gekko) without success.
Sample code here:

```
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()    #instantiate GEKKO object
f = chemical.Flowsheet(m,stream_level=0)  #instantiate flowsheet object
c = chemical.Properties(m)
c.compound('propylene')    #define compound 1
c.compound('propane')      #define compound 2
c.compound('butane')       #define compound 3
c.compound('pentane')      #define compound 4

s1=f.stream(fixed=True)    #define stream 1
s1.x=np.array([0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1])     #specify mole fraction of compound 1-4 for stream1
s1.ndot=10                 #specify molar flow rate of stream 1

s2=f.stream(fixed=True)    
s2.x=np.array([0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2])     #specify mole fraction of compound 1-4 for stream2
s2.ndot=20                 #specify molar flow rate of stream 2

outlet=f.stream(fixed=False) #define outlet stream that should be solved

mx = f.mixer(ni=2)        #mixer object with two inlet
#mx.inlet[0]=s1
#mx.inlet[1]=s2
f.connect(mx.inlet[0],s1)  #assign stream 1 to mixer inlet 1
f.connect(mx.inlet[1],s2)  #assign stream 2 to mixer inlet 2


mx.outlet=outlet  #connect mixer outlet to outlet stream obj
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

print('Mole fractions in blended stream is:',  mx.outlet.x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize each `x[i]` component of the inlet streams with:

```py
inlet1 = [0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]
inlet2 = [0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2] 
for i in range(4):
    s1.x[i].value = inlet1[i]
    s2.x[i].value = inlet2[i]
```

Use the `stream` object on the left hand side of the connection function. The connection function keeps the object on the left side (1st argument) and removes the 2nd object reference (e.g. `f.connect(keep,remove)`). The outlet stream also needs a connection:

```py
f.connect(outlet,mx.outlet)
```

Here is a complete script:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO, chemical
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()    #instantiate GEKKO object
f = chemical.Flowsheet(m,stream_level=0)  #instantiate flowsheet object
c = chemical.Properties(m)
c.compound('propylene')    #define compound 1
c.compound('propane')      #define compound 2
c.compound('butane')       #define compound 3
c.compound('pentane')      #define compound 4

s1=f.stream(fixed=True)    #define stream 1
inlet1 = [0.5,0.3,0.1,0.1]     #specify mole fraction of compound 1-4 for stream1
s1.ndot=10                 #specify molar flow rate of stream 1

s2=f.stream(fixed=True)    
inlet2 = [0.3,0.3,0.2,0.2]     #specify mole fraction of compound 1-4 for stream2
s2.ndot=20                 #specify molar flow rate of stream 2

for i in range(4):
    s1.x[i].value = inlet1[i]
    s2.x[i].value = inlet2[i]

outlet=f.stream(fixed=False) #define outlet stream that should be solved

mx = f.mixer(ni=2)        #mixer object with two inlet
#mx.inlet[0]=s1
#mx.inlet[1]=s2
f.connect(s1,mx.inlet[0])  #assign stream 1 to mixer inlet 1
f.connect(s2,mx.inlet[1])  #assign stream 2 to mixer inlet 2
f.connect(outlet,mx.outlet)
#mx.outlet=outlet  #connect mixer outlet to outlet stream obj
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

print('Mole fractions in blended stream is:',  outlet.x)
# Open run folder to see more detail from model and results
# m.open_folder()
```

This gives the blending solution:

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  7.40741E-20  1.11111E+00
    1  1.08350E-35  1.15741E-01
    2  1.08350E-35  1.15741E-01
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.279999999678694E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 
Mole fractions in blended stream is: [[0.4], [0.3], [0.15], [0.15]]
```